# Combining more than 32 input files in FFmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg through Node.js via fluent-ffmpeg to combine a number of small audio files into one.  Each of the audio files I am combining has a delayed start time (so it's neither merging all at the same start, nor concat'ing).  I can do this successfully using [`aevalsrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aevalsrc)`=0` and [`concat`ing](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) my audio file to that, and then [`amix`ing](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) everything down.  However, although I couldn't find reference to a maximum number of inputs in the documentation, I got `[amix @ 0x3fcd920] Value 78.000000 for parameter 'inputs' out of range [1 - 32]` when trying to `amix` 78 files.  Clearly there is a limit of 32 input files.

Given this limitation, I am unsure of the best way to proceed.  I understand that [`amerge`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge-1) exists, but it stops after the shortest file length, so I would need to [`apad`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) everything and I just tested it and determined that `amerge` has a limit of 64 input files, which won't always suit my needs (I have an arbitrary number of inputs).

I *could* `amix` 32 files, store that somewhere, `amix` 32 more, etc, and `amix` the results.  I would prefer to not deal with writing temp files to disk to then have to clean up later.  I considered writing the "temp" outputs to duplex Node streams and reading from them in my final mixdown, but I fear that may be rather inefficient.

Below is what I am currently doing. If this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and this is a dumb way to accomplish what I want, please let me know.

```
ffmpeg()
    //INPUTS
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/bd/bd5025.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/bd/bd5025.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/bd/bd5025.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/sd/sd5025.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/sd/sd5025.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/rs/rs.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/rs/rs.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/rs/rs.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/cp/cp.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/cp/cp.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/cp/cp.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/oh/oh25.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/oh/oh25.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/oh/oh25.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/ch/ch.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/ch/ch.wav')
    .input('/drummachine/www/audio/ch/ch.wav')
    // ...
    // you get the picture
    // ...
    .audioCodec('libmp3lame').format('mp3')
    .complexFilter([
        //GENERATE SILENCE TO PREPEND TO INPUTS
        'aevalsrc=0:d=6.857142857142857[s78]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=0[s0]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=0.857[s1]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=1.714[s2]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=2.571[s3]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=3.429[s4]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=4.286[s5]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=5.143[s6]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=6[s7]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=0.429[s8]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=1.286[s9]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=2.143[s10]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=3[s11]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=3.857[s12]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=4.714[s13]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=5.571[s14]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=6.429[s15]',
        'aevalsrc=0:d=0.536[s16]',
        // ...
        //CONCAT SILENCE AND AUDIO
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s0', '0:a'], outputs: 'ac0'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s1', '1:a'], outputs: 'ac1'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s2', '2:a'], outputs: 'ac2'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s3', '3:a'], outputs: 'ac3'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s4', '4:a'], outputs: 'ac4'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s5', '5:a'], outputs: 'ac5'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s6', '6:a'], outputs: 'ac6'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s7', '7:a'], outputs: 'ac7'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s8', '8:a'], outputs: 'ac8'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s9', '9:a'], outputs: 'ac9'},
        {filter: 'concat', options: {v: 0, a: 1}, inputs: ['s10', '10:a'], outputs: 'ac10'},
        // ...
        // again, this goes on for a while
        // ...
        //MIX IT ALL
        {filter: 'amix', options: {inputs: 78, duration: 'longest'},
            inputs: ['s78', 'ac0', 'ac1', 'ac2', 'ac3', 'ac4', 'ac5',
            'ac6', 'ac7', 'ac8', 'ac9', 'ac10', 'ac11', 'ac12', 'ac13',
            'ac14', 'ac15', 'ac16', 'ac17', 'ac18', 'ac19', 'ac20',    
            // ...
            'ac74', 'ac75', 'ac76'], outputs: 'out'}], 'out')
    //ERROR
    .on('error', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
        console.log('ffmpeg stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('ffmpeg stderr: ' + stderr);
    //SUCCESS
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log('Processing finished !');
        res.end();
    }).pipe(res);
```

Comment: ' I would prefer to not deal with writing temp files to disk to then have to clean up later.' with tmp module you an track the tmp items created and get them deleted automatically at the end of the process. see https://github.com/bruce/node-temp + track

Comment: How about recursive amixes? amix 1-26, 27-52 and 53-78 and then amix those.

Comment: @mh-cbon That sounds intriguing; I'll look into that

Comment: @Mulvya From what I understand (not an ffmpeg expert), I can't do that in one command, so I'd have to amix a number of files, store that temporary output somehow, repeat, and then amix down my final and then delete my temp files, and try to ensure I have good enough error handling to make sure those files get cleaned up even if ffmpeg errors out (although `node-temp` might be the ticket I am looking for.) Otherwise, if there's some cool way to do it all in memory, I am not aware of how to do that

Comment: I m unsure about your current ffmpeg module. Have you check https://github.com/trenskow/stream-transcoder.js ? fluent-ffmpeg can take a readable in input too.

Comment: Basic syntax would be `[0]..[25]amix=inputs=26[a1];[26]..[51]amix=inputs=26[a2];[52]..[77]amix=inputs=26[a3];[a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=3[out]` . Now, this may not work because of memory issues. In which try inserting `afifo` after each of the initial amix filters i.e. `[0]..[25]amix=inputs=26,afifo[a1]`. Or it may be buggy in other ways, but worth a try.

Comment: @Mulvya That sounds promising, and easier than adding more Node dependencies.  I'll have a look at how to do that in `fluent` in a bit and see how that works.  Thanks for the info!